# CouchDB: How to replicate a database with its security settings

Tags: couchdb

I have a database called `CouchDB_SomeClient_live`. I then have this database replicating to a database `CouchDB_SomeClient_live_shadow`, which I use to test database operations before doing anything on the live database.

The idea is that at any time the shadow can be deleted and it will be recreated as a copy of the live system. This works fine, but I always manually have to add security settings.

1. How can I get the shadow to be recreated with the same security
   settings as the live DB?
2. How and where are the actual database security settings handled by Couch?

The replication document has the following settings:

```
{
   "_id": "pull_CouchDB_SomeClient_live_to_shadow",
   "source": "CouchDB_SomeClient_live",
   "target": "CouchDB_SomeClient_live_shadow",
   "create_target": true,
   "continuous": true,
   "user_ctx": {
       "name": "admin",
       "roles": [
           "_admin"
       ]
   },
   "owner": "zach"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line script to copy the security settings, e.g.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT http://admin:admin_password@localhost:5984/foo/_security -d $(curl -X GET admin:admin_password@localhost:5984/foo/_security)
```

Source: [CouchDB full replication](http://mussol.org/2013/10/23/how-to-couchdb-full-replication/)